# Why aren't these combinational logic Systemverilog descriptions equivalent

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, vivado

I have two 4-bit signals representing binary coded decimals for the hours of a clock in 24 hour format: h1_24h and h0_24h, for the most significant and least significant digit respectively.

i need a combinational block of logic to produce two other 4-bit signals h1_12h and h0_12h: the corresponding binary coded decimals for the hour if it was in 12 hour format, for example if h1_24h = 4'd1 and h0_24h = 4'd9, then h1_12h = 4'd0 and h0_12h = 4'd7, because 19 in 24 hour format corresponds to 07 (pm) in 12 hour format.

my first try is as follows:

```
always_comb begin
    {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {h1_24h, h0_24h}; // identical from 01 am to 12 pm
    if (h1_24h == 0 && h0_24h == 0) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd1, 4'd2}; // 00 -> 12
    if (h1_24h == 1 && h0_24h >= 3) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd0, h0_24h - 2}; // 13-19 -> 01-07
    if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h <= 1) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd0, h0_24h + 8}; // 20-21 -> 08-09
    if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h >= 2) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd1, h0_24h - 2}; // 22-23 -> 10-11
end
```

During simulation it seems to work as expected except when the hour is 22 or 23, in those cases it produces 00 and 01 respectively, i checked and the statement `if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h >= 2) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd1, h0_24h - 2};` is properly executed when it should but produces the wrong output and weirdly changing the most significant digit assignment to other values doesn't change the outputs, for example changing the line to `if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h >= 2) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd5, h0_24h - 2};` it still produces 00 and 01.

just in case i tried replacing the single line assignments using concatenation to more simple assignments over multiple lines as follows:

```
always_comb begin
    // identical from 01 am to 12 pm
    h1_12h = h1_24h;
    h0_12h = h0_24h;
    
    // 00 -> 12
    if (h1_24h == 0 && h0_24h == 0) begin
        h1_12h = 4'd1;
        h0_12h = 4'd2;
    end
    
    // 13-19 -> 01-07
    if (h1_24h == 1 && h0_24h >= 3) begin
        h1_12h = 4'd0;
        h0_12h = h0_24h - 2;
    end
    
    // 20-21 -> 08-09
    if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h <= 1) begin
        h1_12h = 4'd0;
        h0_12h = h0_24h + 8;
    end
    
    // 22-23 -> 10-11
    if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h >= 2) begin
        h1_12h = 4'b1;
        h0_12h = h0_24h - 2;
    end
end
```

Surprisingly the above produces the correct results during simulation but i'm left wondering why the former description didn't work as opposed to the latter. In case it matters i'm using Vivado 2023.1.

Answer (score 2):

It is because h024h-2 does not have bit width specified for concatenation.
I added cast to 4 bit to limit "h024h-2" output width.
below fix in your code solves the issue.

```
typedef bit[3:0] hrs;

if (h1_24h == 2 && h0_24h >= 2) {h1_12h, h0_12h} = {4'd1, hrs'((h0_24h - 2))};
```